What is the maximum number of edges in a graph with n vertices
The maximum number of edges in a graph with 
n vertices depends on whether the graph is directed or undirected.
It looks like you're asking about the maximum number of edges in a graph with 
n vertices and how this depends on whether the graph is directed or undirected.

Is there a question there? It looks like you just pasted a ChatGPT answer

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Lets consider undirected graph.
For n = 4. undirected graph would look like this.
(V.a)--(V.b)
  |  \/  |
  |  /\  |
(V.c)--(V.d)


In an undirected graph, each edge connects two vertices, and each vertex can be connected to at most (n-1) other vertices.
Therefore, the total number of possible edges is the sum of the number of connections each vertex can have, which is (n-1) + (n-2) + ... + 2 + 1 = n(n-1)/2.


In a directed graph, each edge has a direction, going from one vertex to another. Therefore, for each pair of vertices, you can have two possible edges (one in each direction).
The number of possible edges in a complete directed graph with n vertices is given by: 2 x (
(

−
1
)/2) = 
(

−
1
)
